# Is there any way to listen to changes on an input range in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm developing an app with Angular 2.0, and I don't know how to listen to an input range changes.

Here's the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'zoom-slider',
  styleUrls: [
    './zoom-slider.style.scss'
  ],
  template: `
    <div class="zoom-slider">
      <input type="range" max="5" (click)="changeZoom"/>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ZoomSlider {

  changeZoom() {
    console.log('change slider');
  }

}
```

This doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I faced this error I solved this error by : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75516361/14828354

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to listen for the change event and have a reference to the input.

```
<input type="range" #ref (change)="changeZoom(ref.value)"/>

changeZoom(value: number) { ... }
```

Answer (score 10):

I guess one of these should work

```
<input type="range" max="5" (input)="changeZoom($event)"/>
<input type="range" max="5" (change)="changeZoom($event)"/>
```

If you pass the function as above `(click)` might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// HTML
<input type="range" (input)="onChangeFunction($event)">

//TS
onChangeFunction(event: Event){
  const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
}
```

You can also add "min="0" max="100" step="25" for example

Answer (score 0):

This error can be solved by:

```
<input type="range" (change)="changeZoom($event.target)"/>
```

and in function:

```
changeZoom(val: any) { 
    console.log(val.value);
 }
```